# C equivalent for std::basic_string::find_last_not_of

Tags: c, stdstring, crt

I want to know if CRT offers a function similar to find_last_not_of() offered by STL. I searched but found equivalents of searching (for the first non-occurence) from the beginning of the string. but none of them searched backwards (starting from the end of the string). All of them searched in the forward direction starting from the first char.

Comment: `man 3 string` Enjoy!

Comment: There's no such function in the C standard library, but isn't it trivial to do yourself?

Comment: It's damn trivial. But i wanted to use the standard stuff from library.

Comment: well, it's not in the *standard* library (as specified by the C standard), so ... do it yourself :)

Comment: q&d sketch: `const char *strlastnotin(const char *s, const char *list){ const char *res = 0; for(const char *p = s; *p; ++p){ if (!strchr(list, p) res = p; } return res; }`